# Cannot transfer Schema role to another Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I've inherited a small data center that is setup with two domain controllers. The first domain controller (that is home to the five operational masters roles (win2003server) is an older server and I want to move the operational masters to the other domain controller server (win2003r2 server).

When I go to the Active Directory Scheme mmc plug-in, and go to Operations Master, the Change button is greyed out. Do I need to move the other roles first prior to moving the Schema Master role or is this greyed out for another reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are likely not a member of the Schema Admins group.  You need that group membership to transfer the schema master role.

Comment: If you still cannot change it after adding the user to the "Schema Admin" group, try closing the windows session and re-logging in. This was necessary for me on a Windows 2003 Domain Controller

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are connected to the Schema Partition on the new (r2) domain controller. You cannot do it from the one that already holds the FSMO role.

Open the Schema snap-in, right-click **Active Directory Schema**, and then select **Change Domain Controller** to connect to another domain controller.

Comment: I was sure to do this, and you're right this would cause the Change button to grey

Answer (score 0):

When its greyed out its normally as your trying to PUSH the role out, try pulling from the other DC

http://www.techieshelp.com/how-to-transfer-fsmo-roles-graphical-and-command-line/